# Transfer of data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which contains login table and registration table. 
I have columns username and password in registration table.
when these columns are filled i want them to also appear on the login table automatically.
Can anyone suggest me how to get this effect

Comment: You need trigger on insert. have a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple one is use trigger as after insert on registration table,
Inside trigger write into login table.

Answer (score 0):

Use an insert trigger to add the data to the other table

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER reg_trigger AFTER INSERT ON registration
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into login (username, password) 
    VALUES (NEW.username, NEW.password);
END
|
delimiter ;
```